# Get words from trie containing specific letters

Tags: python, string, trie

I'd like to retrieve words from a trie that contain specific letters. For example: List all words that contain the letters [a, g]. If my trie has the words ["APPLE", "EGG", "CAR", "BLUE", "AGRICULTURE", "DONE"] it would return "AGRICULTURE".

This is a very simple trie implementation

```
def load_trie(words):
    root = {}
    for word in words:
        curr_node = root
        for letter in word:
            curr_node = curr_node.setdefault(letter, {})
        curr_node.setdefault('', True)
    return root

with open('sowpods') as word_list:
    words = [word.strip().upper() for word in word_list]
    
TRIE = load_trie(words)
```

If I can check for words containing specific letters, it would also be nice to look for words that **don't** contain specific letters.

Comment: What's the contents of `'sowpods'`, and are you required to use a trie?

Comment: you can use the `re` library with re.search https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match

Comment: You can't know if the letter is in one of the words until you've looked at the whole word — it's always possible the letter in question is the last letter. So you might as well make a function that yields all the words and filter it. For words the *don't* contain the letter you can prune the branches with those keys.

Comment: "The name SOWPODS was coined as an anagram of OSW+OSPD, the names of the two lexicons (the British Official Scrabble Words and the American Official SCRABBLE Players Dictionary) that were originally merged to form SOWPODS."  -- https://scrabbleplayers.org/w/SOWPODS

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark sowpods is basically just a huge list of English words. That's why I want to use a trie, to have a fast search.

Answer (score 0):

@Mark offers a helpful remark about the dual problem:

> For words the *don't* contain the letter you can prune the branches with those keys.

Now, how could we make a trie, or any tree,
well adapted to the primal problem?
Let's see.
A standard answer for the Anagram Problem
is to store sorted letter sets

```
for word in vocabulary:
    set_to_word[sorted(word)].append(word)
```

and then

```
set_to_word.get(sorted(target_word))
```

will reveal all corresponding anagrams.

To adapt this to a trie, we want frequent letters
near the root.
Here is one plausible frequency ordering of the alphabet:

E T A O I N S R H L D C U M F P G W Y B V K X J Q Z

Rather than the `sorted( ... )` permutation,
permute words by etaoin,
and take advantage of the fact that hits will
often result in a hit near the root.
In this scheme "tears" would map to "etasr".

For the dual problem,
simply store the complement set of letters,
obeying the same ordering.
So "tears" maps to a 21-character string,
or perhaps some prefix truncation would suffice.